# a word that is commonly used as either an adjective or a noun

Tags: nouns, adjectives, ambiguity

I'm trying to come up with some sort of play on word, but for that I need a common word that can be used as either a noun or an adjective. here is what I am trying to write:

*you are a little [word]*

which is a phrase that can be interpreted as either

*you are a little bit [adjective]*

or

*you are one little [noun]*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for (comedy) resources.

Answer (score 3):

*light*, *short*, *drunk*, *orange*, *cold*

Comment: drunk are orange work very well!

Answer (score 0):

Do homophones count? There's a common joke that goes along the lines of "Are you a pony now? I heard you were a little hoarse."

Comment: no, I'm not looking for an homophone